# How to notify view that the variable state has been updated from a extracted subview in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a view that contain users `UsersContentView` in this view there is a button which is extracted as a subview: `RequestSearchButton()`, and under the button there is a `Text` view which display the result if the user did request to search or no, and it is also extracted as a subview `ResultSearchQuery()`.

```
struct UsersContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                RequestSearchButton()
                
                ResultSearchQuery(didUserRequestSearchOrNo: .constant("YES"))
            }
            
            
            
        }
        
    }
}


struct RequestSearchButton: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            
        }) {
            Text("User requested search")
        }
    }
}



struct ResultSearchQuery: View {
    @Binding var didUserRequestSearchOrNo: String
    var body: some View {
        Text("Did user request search: \(didUserRequestSearchOrNo)")
    }
}
```

How can I update the `@Binding var didUserRequestSearchOrNo: String` inside the `ResultSearchQuery()` When the button `RequestSearchButton()` is clicked. Its so confusing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track the State of a variable (which is indicating if a search is active or not) in your parent view, or your ViewModel if you want to extract the Variables. Then you can refer to this variable in enclosed child views like the Search Button or Search Query Results.

In this case a would prefer a Boolean value for the tracking because it's easy to handle and clear in meaning.

```
struct UsersContentView: View {
    
    @State var requestedSearch = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                RequestSearchButton(requestedSearch: $requestedSearch)
                
                ResultSearchQuery(requestedSearch: $requestedSearch)
            }
            
            
            
        }
        
    }
}

struct RequestSearchButton: View {
    @Binding var requestedSearch: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            requestedSearch.toggle()
        }) {
            Text("User requested search")
        }
    }
}



struct ResultSearchQuery: View {
    @Binding var requestedSearch: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Text("Did user request search: \(requestedSearch.description)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I couldn't understand why you used two struct which are connected to eachother, you can do it in one struct and Control with a state var

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

            VStack {
                
                RequestSearchButton()

        }
        
    }
}


struct RequestSearchButton: View {
    
    @State private var clicked : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            
            clicked = true
            
        }) {
            
            Text("User requested search")
            
        }
        
        Text("Did user request search: \(clicked == true ? "YES" : "NO")")
        
    }
}
```

if this is not what you are looking for, could you make a detailed explain.

Comment: this won't help me, sometimes i have a lot of structures, xcode make me break the code to run it or it will not run, so i need an answer with those structures.